# @Test gives unresolved reference - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, compilation, junit5

I am trying to run a Kotlin test, but the `@Test` annotation is unresolved

```kotlin
// snippet
import kotlin.test.*
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

sealed class Transport
data class Train(val line: String) : Transport()

fun travel(transport: Transport) = "Train S1"

class TestTest {
    @Test
    fun `train travel`() {
        assertEquals("Train S1", travel(Train("S1")))
    }
}
```

I have the `kotlin-test` dependency in **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:$junit_version"
}
```

What is the problem here?

I am using **IntelliJ 2020.2.3 Build Oct 6 2020 Version 11.0.8**

Comment: please add detail of your question

Comment: what is the path of that file? cos with those dependencies, org.junit.Test can only be imported and used in the test package..